# Admin denied access to Ubercart Store when running Ubercart SSL

Tags: ubercart, ssl

I am running the Ubercart SSL module (not Secure Pages) for my Drupal 7.12 site.  I am unable to checkout an order as admin, and I get an access denied message when I try access my store.

Ideas?

Comment: I just now set the Ubercart Non-SSL Switch to Disabled, and I can get into my store and also get to checkout, but I don't want this.  I only want https on checkout, and http elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the Secure Pages module http://drupal.org/project/securepages and I've create a small write up on how to set up Secure Pages with UC http://drupal.org/node/1586258